# Add zeros at front

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are using sharepoint online I have a column that contain customer IDs, most of these IDs are 6 numeric characters, however some of them are less.

I would like to add following 
if ID is < 5 add 0 at front 
if ID is < 4 add 00 at front 
if ID is < 3 add 000 at front 
if ID is < 2 add 0000 at front 
if ID is < 1 add 00000 at front

thank you

Comment: probably a workflow to set another column because IDs can't be in calculated columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula to check the length of Customer IDs value and complete it if the length of it is less than 6.

```
IF(LEN([CustomerIDs])=1,
"00000"&[CustomerIDs],
IF(LEN([CustomerIDs])=2,
"0000"&[CustomerIDs],
IF(LEN([CustomerIDs])=3,
"000"&[CustomerIDs],
IF(LEN([CustomerIDs])=4,
"00"&[CustomerIDs],
IF(LEN([CustomerIDs])=5,
"0"&[CustomerIDs],
[CustomerIDs])))))
```

[Calculated Field Formulas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)